# translating from screen coordinates to real life coordinates

Tags: opencv, math

I have a camera with an object detector model that gives me the x and y position of an object I'm tracking but I want to convert these coordinates to the real life coordinates of the object that moves in a 20mX20m area, my camera has a 80 degree FOV, is tilted by about 30 degrees and is 5m away from the 20mX20m area

Answer (score 0):

We need a couple more details in your question to fully answer it, but I'll assume that the camera is placed 5m from the center of the 20m x 20m area, and that the FOV is 80 degrees *both* horizontally and vertically.

Let *X* = (*x* * 80deg / *width*) - 40deg, where *x* is the image coordinate and *width* is the image width in pixels. Then *X* represents the offset in degrees from a straight line from the camera.

Likewise for *Y*. *Y* = (*y* * 80deg / *height*).

Then posX = tan(*X*) * 5m + 10m and posY = tan(*Y* + tilt) * 5m + 10m.

Make sure that the direction of your tilt and of your y-coordinates agree - and that you convert to radians if necessary (x PI/180).

Also, if the camera is *not* placed in front of the center of the 20m x 20m area, change the +10m to the correct camOffsetX and camOffsetY.

Since most cameras today use [rectilinear lenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectilinear_lens), there will be a small discrepancy from the actual position most noticeable around a 20deg offset, but it should be pretty minor.